# Understanding Depolarisation Ratio in Raman Spectroscopy

Tags: raman-spectroscopy, optics

So the depolarisation ratio is given by the ratio of the scattered intensities

\begin{equation}
\rho = \frac{I_{\text{perpendicular}}}{I_\text{parallel}}
\end{equation}

My understanding of this is that if I was to shine a laser through a polariser, and take the Raman spectrum, then rotate that polariser by 90 degrees, and take the Raman spectrum again, the ratio of the peaks would give me my depolarisation ratio for each Raman signal?

Or is it that we take the Raman spectrum with unpolarised light, then take the spectrum with a polariser in place, then take the ratio of those? If not, would this be anything of note?

Thank you